# Set default help type for the help system in R for Windows

Tags: r, windows

In Linux, the R help system by default uses the in-console pager for viewing the help manual. But in Windows the default method used is html, that is, opening the manual in the browser. I can open the text manual by using the `help_type` argument, like this:

```
> help (help, help_type = "text")
```

I was wondering how to set this as the default argument of help function, so that I can use the `?` shortcut (because then won't need to pass the `help_text` argument). Also, it would be extra sweet if the text manual opened inside the console (I already have git-for-windows's `less` program in the PATH). As of now, it opens in R's own pager.

Comment: [`options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html)`(help_type="text")`  (or whichever you prefer).

Comment: Yeah, just found it. Cannot set the pager, though.

Comment: For others: you need to put quotes around `help_type`, as it's not an object. See the answer below.

Comment: What do you mean? `options(help_type="text")` works just fine. (It's only in `getOption)` that you need to quote it, that function does not use non-standard evaluation.)

Comment: @r2evans, you're right. I got confused.

Comment: And got the option to set the default pager, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the default for `help_type` option:

```
> options (help_type = "text")
> getOption ("help_type")
[1] "text"
```

And, to set the console as the pager instead of R's internal one:

```
> options (pager = "console")
> getOption ("pager")
[1] "console"
```

You can even set a particular command as the pager. For example, if you want to use unix's `less` program provided by cygwin or msys2 or git for Windows:

```
> options (pager = "less")
> getOption ("pager")
[1] "less"
```

N.B. Make sure that `less` is in your `path`. Otherwise, you would have to provide the full path of it:

```
> options (pager = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\less.exe")
```

Where the `less` program is situated in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\`.

See `?options` and `?file.show` for details.